# Organising user interface on wallet screen in banking application

Tags: gui-design

The screen below in my app displays wallet and current balance information.

I think it is very difficult at the moment to distinguish between the two.

How can I better display this information to the reader? What would be the best way of organising it?

Wallet is meant to give information on the user’s wallet address and provide them with a QR code that they can share with friends, when they need to transact (ie send/receive money).

Balance tells the user how much money is left in their account.

[image]

Comment: You haven't described two things. Wallet and Balance... What's the difference?

Comment: Can you please able to say why you add the QR code over here.... is it for adding balance to your wallet ?

Comment: I’ve updated the question with more detail. Yes, the QR code is meant for sharing with friends and businesses when needing to transact

Comment: i will add the suggestion in answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here have some key point to change:

- in this section the highlighted things should be the user's wallet balance. so keep the the balance at top. then put the balances (Bitcoin and GBP) then
- add a title that should define why you are using the QR code
- make the Qr code large and don't put the button to make it large
- remove the refresh button and instead of that you can add scroll refresh system (having on the top screen scroll, just like facebook refresh  )

**make the thing to make it too minimal with user efficiency**

here i added a image may be well define your problems :)

[image]

Comment: You are welcome @methuselah